# Datasheet supply voltage range

Tags: datasheet

I am reading though a datasheet of [TL064](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/75402.pdf) and I am unable to find supply voltage range of this component. I've experienced this couple of times with datasheets...

Farnell states its supply voltage range being: 7V to 36V, ± 18V. Where from the datasheet did they get that info?

Comment: Page 5? the table with "Supply voltage"?

Comment: @PlasmaHH Damn, was just about to say that too.  Absolute maximums - Vcc+ = +18v, Vcc- = -18v

Comment: Maximum yes, what about the minimum: 7V?

Comment: Also according to figure 4, page 11, the device is tested in the range of about \$\pm 2 V\$ up to \$\pm 15 V\$. I would say that this is the recommended supply range.

Comment: I think they made the 7V up. Look at the graphs - they all go from +/- 2V

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never ever trust the technical data given by the webpage of a distributor, they can be horrendously wrong (I've seen buck converters being sold as boost converters and voltage ratings beyond everything the chip could handle).

The datasheet on this part isn't very helpful with respect to the minimum required voltage. But the [product page](http://www.ti.com/product/tl064) from TI lists the minimum required voltage:

Total Supply Voltage (Min) (+5V=5, +/-5V=10): 7V

Total Supply Voltage (Max) (+5V=5, +/-5V=10): 36V

But as others pointed out, the datasheet shows figures where the supply voltage is below 2V, so what's the right answer? As I don't know, I've asked in the E2E forum for clarification, and this is what I got as response from Ron Michallick (a TI employee (who holds no liability etc.)):

> Minimum input common mode can be as high as [VCC-] + 4V so any supply
>   under 4V is very risky. The output is also not rail to rail so using
>   below 7V would be quite limited.
>
> For anything less than +/-5V supply I would strongly suggest an
>   alternative op-amp.